# How to configure tab completion for my own function in MATLAB 2016 ( both a and b )?

Tags: matlab, tab-completion

In older versions of MATLAB, one can configure tab completion by editing the TC.xml file located in matlabroot\toolbox\local. In MATLAB 2016 (both a and b), though, that file no longer exists.

How can I set up auto tab completion for my own function in MATLAB 2016 ?

Comment: Is this 2016a or b? You should probably specify in both your title, question, and answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out, MATLAB 2016 (both 2016a and 2016b) uses a `functionSignatures.json` file to configure automatic tab completion. One can easily read the content of any such file you find within the `$matlabroot\toolbox\` folder to understand how it works.

Here is a very simple example `functionSignatures.json` file showing how to set up tab completion for a function named `nd2finfo` :

```
{
"nd2finfo":
{
  "inputs":
  [
    {"name":"nd2file", "kind":"required", "type":"filepath=*.nd2" }
  ]
}
}
```

This file should be saved within the same folder that has the function definition. While typing in the function input, upon pressing tab, I can see a list of files with the extension .nd2 popping up.